# Payment Express Checkout integration with Magento 2

Tags: payment-gateway, express-checkout, magento2.2

I'm trying to configure "payment express checkout" in magento-2. However, don't know what to put in below fields. Screen-shot is attached.

PxPay UserId ?
PxPay Key ?
PxPay Url ?

PxPost Username ?
PxPost Password ?
PxPost Url ?

[image]

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Those details should have supplied to you by the provider. If you have received that email the relevant information and which field it relates to is pretty straight forward.
If you haven't received anything then simply contact them for the details.